# How do I display an alphabetic list of all customers who placed an order in specific year?

Tags: sql

I have created a database with the tables `Customers` and `Orders`.

`Customer` have the following fields,

```
CustomerNo 
Customer name
CustomerAddress
```

And the `Orders` has:

```
OrderNo
OrderDate
CustomerNo
```

One of the main objectives is to list

"An alphabetic list of all customers who placed an order in 2014 without duplicates"

This is what I've come up.

```
select Customers * from CustomerName order by CustomerName ASC
```

Its probably not even correct.

Thanks.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That YEAR function is product specific.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select Customers.* 
from Customers 
INNER JOIN OrderTable On Customers.CustomerNo = OrderTable.CustomerNo 
WHERE YEAR(OrderDate) = 2014
ORDER BY CustomerName Desc
```